# Web Form For Marketeres Report in HTML format on Front end

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am new in Sitecore Development and I am working with web for for marketers Sitecore module, is Sitecore provides any functionality to show form reports in HTML format on front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sitecore by default not provide any functionality to show form reports in HTML format from front end, But I did it for my one project you can find solution in my Blog

http://sitecoretweaks.wordpress.com/2014/07/07/display-web-forms-for-marketers-form-submissions-outside-of-the-form-reports-2/

Comment: Hey Yogesh is your given code will support Sitecore 7

Comment: Yes, I have not tried with Sitecore 7 but I hope it will work

Comment: Thanks, I'll try and let you know

Comment: Yeah sure if you have any problem in given code let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [Sitecore CMS Modules
Web Forms for Marketers 2](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/products/web_forms2/web_forms_for_marketers_v2_reference_usletter.pdf)

> Information about visitor activity on forms can be viewed in various
>   reports provided by the module. To open form reports, log in Sitecore
>   desktop and click Sitecore – All Applications – Web Forms for 
>   Marketers – Form Reports and select the form for which you want to
>   view reports. Alternatively, in the  Content Editor, select the form
>   under the /sitecore/system/Modules/Web Forms for Marketers/Website 
>   item and click Form Reports. All reports display last 200 records by
>   default. To change this number, you should open the report in the 
>   Windows Designer and change the value in the appropriate SQL query.

I hope this will help you !

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know to see reports but I want to render report in HTML format from front end to show the client, And client want to see report without login in Sitecore as a extranet user

Comment: @Mark maybe decompile the module and use the same queries to build your own page that does that ?

Comment: I'd be careful about creating a front-facing user data report. Openly showing user data without security will get you into major trouble. That's a huge privacy concern.
I'd assess why the client wants to avoid logging into Sitecore, and talk to them about the security implications.

Comment: Hello @nsgocev yes you are right that security is a big issue in this but this given code is only responsible to get report on front end we can create security on front end as well via sitecore and extranet user both